# Struggling to create a php array to fetch photos from directory that can be used as an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Basically I am trying to create a photo slideshow that will display specific photos depending on the userid. These photos will be stored in the directory of my web server space. Currently I have a html (not changed into php) file with basic html layout, css style sheet and an external js file that has my code that makes the photos fade in and out. I have added php at the bottom of my html. This is what I have:

```
$user_id = $_GET['userid'];
print "<h1> Hi,  $user_id </h1>";

function returnimages($dirname = "Photos/1") {   //will replace 1 with userid once something starts working
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
//Output it as a JavaScript array element
echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
$curimage++;
}
}

closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names

?>
```

and in my javscript, the code I had before for the array of photos:

```
// List of images for user one
var userphoto = new Array();
userphoto[0] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";
    userphoto[1] = "Photos/1/2.jpg";
        userphoto[2] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";
            userphoto[3] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";
                userphoto[4] = "Photos/1/1.jpg";
```

which I have now commented out and replaced it with this:

```
var userphoto = <? echo json_encode($galleryarray); ?>;
```

I am hoping to be able to change the src of photodisplay with the new array:

photodisplay[x].attr("src", userphoto[x]);

Sorry if my problem is not clear at all. I am very confused myself. :( hopefully someone can help!

Comment: First, do you have PHP debugging set up?  Are you able to verify that the server is getting the files described?  Second, mixing PHP and Javascript directly qualifies as a BAD IDEA.  Finally, I suggest outputting the file array as `return json_encode($files)`.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for replying! No I don't :S and I think the server is getting the files because at the bottom of the page it prints out Array();galleryarray[0]="1.jpg";galleryarray[1]="2.jpg"; 

I'm confused :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id = (int) $_GET['userid'];
print "<h1> Hi,  $user_id </h1>";

function returnimages($dirname = "Photos/1") {
    $dirname = str_replace('..', '.', $dirname); //only remove this if you know why it's here
    $pattern = "*{.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif}"; //valid image extensions
    return glob($dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $pattern, GLOB_BRACE);
}

echo "var galleryarray = ".json_encode(returnimages()).";\n";
?>
```

Also, you should use `<?= json_encode($ret) ?>` because the PHP short tag (`<?`) is deprecated, but `<?=` is not, and is the equivalent of `<?php echo`.